# plot not appearing in shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to plot using `ggplot` but my shiny app is not displaying the plot.

Here is the code:

```
getUI <-function(completesurvey){
  return(
  fluidPage(

  # Application title
  titlePanel("Hacker Rank Developer Survey"),

  # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      p("Hacker Rank is a survey conducted among 25,000 participants all around the globe"),
      p("There were students,professionals and Hiring managers who participated in the survey"),
      p("Select of various categories based on Gender,total survey respondents and "),

      selectInput("SurveyRespondents",
                  "Choose the categories",
                  choices = c("Total Survey respondents","Male vs Female","Students Vs Developers"),
                  selected = "Total Survey respondents")

    ),


    # Show a plot of the generated distribution
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput('ResPlot')
    )

  ),
  br(),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      p("Hacker Rank is a survey conducted among 25,000 participants all around the globe"),
      p("There were students,professionals and Hiring managers who participated in the survey"),
      p("Select of various categories based on Gender,total survey respondents and "),

      selectInput("Survey Respondents",
                  "Choose the categories",
                  choices = c("Total Survey respondents","Male vs Female","Students Vs Developers"),
                  selected = "Total Survey respondents")

    ),


    # Show a plot of the generated distribution
    mainPanel(plotOutput("RespPlot"))

  ),
  br(),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      p("Hacker Rank is a survey conducted among 25,000 participants all around the globe"),
      p("There were students,professionals and Hiring managers who participated in the survey"),
      p("Select of various categories based on Gender,total survey respondents and "),

      selectInput("Survey Respondents",
                  "Choose the categories",
                  choices = c("Total Survey respondents","Male vs Female","Students Vs Developers"),
                  selected = "Total Survey respondents")

    ),


    # Show a plot of the generated distribution
    mainPanel(plotOutput("RespPlot"))

  )
)
)}
```

No error messages are displayed.

Comment: You have posted 2 times the same UI code, and you have not posted the server code.

Comment: Start stripping your app down to bare essentials and see where it breaks.